# Error exporting inference graph (ValueError)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

So I'm following sentdex's object detection tutorial and I have gotten to the step where you are supposed to export the inference graph. I'm using the "export_inference_graph.py" script from Tensorflow's object_detection folder.
The problem is that I'm getting this ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zelcore-Dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\google\proto
buf\internal\python_message.py", line 545, in _GetFieldByName
    return message_descriptor.fields_by_name[field_name]
KeyError: 'layout_optimizer'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 119, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Zelcore-Dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\p
ython\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 115, in main
    FLAGS.output_directory, input_shape)
  File "C:\Users\Zelcore-Dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\object_detec
tion-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\exporter.py", line 427, in export_inference_graph
    input_shape, optimize_graph, output_collection_name)
  File "C:\Users\Zelcore-Dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\object_detec
tion-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\exporter.py", line 391, in _export_inference_graph
    initializer_nodes='')
  File "C:\Users\Zelcore-Dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\object_detec
tion-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\exporter.py", line 72, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos
    layout_optimizer=rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig.ON)
  File "C:\Users\Zelcore-Dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\google\proto
buf\internal\python_message.py", line 484, in init
    field = _GetFieldByName(message_descriptor, field_name)
  File "C:\Users\Zelcore-Dator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\google\proto
buf\internal\python_message.py", line 548, in _GetFieldByName
    (message_descriptor.name, field_name))
ValueError: Protocol message RewriterConfig has no "layout_optimizer" field.
```

I'm guessing that it has something to do with protobuf, but I've reinstalled it several times already with no success.
All help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happened to me too. Didn't happen few weeks ago.
Until the bug is fixed, you could use an earlier version that still works.
replace line 72 in 'object_detection/exporter.py':

```
layout_optimizer=rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig.ON)
```

with the old and working line:

```
optimize_tensor_layout=True)
```

Comment: Works, but I don't know why.

Comment: Like Craig said below I also reran the install command after changing line 72 to optimize_tensor_layout = true)

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
rewrite_options = rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig(optimize_tensor_layout=True)
```

but kept running into the same issue UNTIL I went and reran

```
python setup.py install
```

from my "research" folder. Then I was able to get everything to work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove ***optimize_tensor_layout=rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig.ON***

change the line 71 in `exporter.py`

```
rewrite_options = rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig(optimize_tensor_layout=rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig.ON)
```

to:

```
rewrite_options = rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig()
```